# fail to match 2 non-COPY variables in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to match 2 variables in Rust. If they are some given types, then handle and consume them; otherwise handle and consume them in another way.

Please see the following simple code, and the problem is in `handle()`.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Value {
    Nil,
    Num(i32),
    Str(String), // NOT COPY
}

fn handle_and_consume_str(s: String) {
    println!("{s}");
}
fn handle_and_consume_values(a: Value, b: Value) {
    println!("{a:?} {b:?}")
}
fn handle(a: Value, b: Value) {
    if let (Value::Nil, Value::Str(s)) = (a, b) { // <<<
        // special case, `a` is Nil and `b` is Str
        handle_and_consume_str(s);
    } else {
        // normal case
        handle_and_consume_values(a, b);
    }
}

fn main() {
    handle(Value::Nil, Value::Nil);
}
```

The complier gives error on both `a` and `b` (I paste `a` part here only):

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `a`
  --> t.rs:20:35
   |
14 | fn handle(a: Value, b: Value) {
   |           - move occurs because `a` has type `Value`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
15 |     if let (Value::Nil, Value::Str(s)) = (a, b) { // <<<
   |                                           - value moved here
...
20 |         handle_and_consume_values(a, b);
   |                                   ^ value used here after move
```

I understand the error. It's about the ownership.

My question is how to achieve my requirement in Rust?

I tried to match the references, `if let (&Value::Nil, &Value::Str(s)) = (&a, &b)`, but it still does not work because `handle_and_consume_str(s)` need to consume `b`.

---

Another question. The `if let` is OK for only 1 variable:

```
    if let Value::Str(s) = a { // move occurs here
        handle_and_consume_str(s); // <-- used here
    } else {
        handle_and_consume_values(Value::Nil, a);  // <-- and here
    }
```

Why this is OK for 1 variable but not for 2 variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is how to achieve my requirement in Rust?

Use a `match`:

```rust
    match (a, b) {
        (Value::Nil, Value::Str(s)) => handle_and_consume_str(s),
        (a, b) => handle_and_consume_values(a, b),
    }
```

> Why this is OK for 1 variable but not for 2 variables?

I'm less sure about that, but my guess would be that it's because for the "two variables" case the compiler has to first move the two values into a tuple, and that is what makes them inaccessible going forward. That is,

```rust
if let (Value::Nil, Value::Str(s)) = (a, b)
```

is

```rust
let _temp = (a, b); <-- consumes `a` and `b` creating `_temp`
if let (Value::Nil, Value::Str(s)) = _temp
```

When matching on a variable the compiler has more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks! The `match` is OK. I tried `match` but I used `(_, _) =>` for the normal case, which does not work. Changing to `(a, b) =>` is Ok.

Comment: Yes it couldn't work, because by that time `a` and `b` have been moved into the tuple which was `match`-ed. So you need to get them back out of there, hence needing to match the tuple not fallback onto the values. Pretty much the same issue as the `if let` case really.

Answer (score 1):

You could borrow `a` and `b` in the function definitions. Like

```
fn handle_and_consume_str(s: &String) {
    println!("{s}");
}
fn handle_and_consume_values(a: &Value, b: &Value) {
    println!("{a:?} {b:?}")
}
fn handle(a: &Value, b: &Value) {
    if let (Value::Nil, Value::Str(s)) = (a, b) {
        handle_and_consume_str(s);
    } else {
        handle_and_consume_values(a, b);
    }
}

fn main() {
    handle(&Value::Nil, &Value::Str(String::from("Test")));
}
```

Comment: I do need to consume the variables in my real program. So this does not help.